# Unable to get Real Time data for Google Analytics on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

I have integrated Google Analytics(v2.0) api in my iPhone Application, but unable to get real time data on **Google Analytics Real Time**.

Have set dispatch interval property to 0

```
  self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:kTrackingId];
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
```

*Receiving category events properly*, but unable to receive RealTime data.

Is it possible to get RealTime data from iPhone Application?

Comment: Place some code regarding API integration .

Comment: It happened to me too. the v2.0 is still in Beta so i decided to go for 1.x version that will give you "real time" data you want but not the full power of the 2.0 version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved issue by implementing view tracking. RealTime data can only be seen by implementing view tracking.

Demo code:

HomeViewcontroller.h

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface HomeScreenViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

HomeViewcontroller.m

```
//--- Add in viewDidLoad ---//
    self.trackedViewName = @"Home Screen";
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get real time data if you have integrated the API properly  and don't forget to set the correct `trackerWithTrackingId` for your app which you register in google analytics it starts with `UA` prefix

```
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
        // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
        // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
        // Create tracker instance.
    self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-YOURAPPID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another API - Google Real Time API which provides facility as same. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide